# Alternative for ggimage (geom_image) for Kaggle

Tags: r, ggplot2, kaggle, ggimage

I am trying to plot a bar plot for a movie dataset. I want to plot the movie image/icon at the top of the bar for each movie in a plot. I am using the following code to achieve this in R studio for PC:

```
top_voted <- animated_movies[, .(title, vote_count)][order(-vote_count)][1:10]
top_voted$title <- factor(top_voted$title, levels = top_voted$title)
top_voted$image_url<-c("https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_insideout_19751_af12286c.jpeg",
                       "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Up_%282009_film%29.jpg",
                       "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmYxZjg3OWEtNzg5Yi00M2YzLWI1YzYtYTQ0NTgwNzhjN2E1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_.jpg,",
                       "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYjQ5NjM0Y2YtNjZkNC00ZDhkLWJjMWItN2QyNzFkMDE3ZjAxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODIxMzk5NjA@._V1_.jpg",
                       "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_walle_19753_69f7ff00.jpeg",
                       "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_monstersinc_19751_55afa07a.jpeg",
                       "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDU2ZWJlMjktMTRhMy00ZTA5LWEzNDgtYmNmZTEwZTViZWJkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDQ2OTk4MzI@._V1_.jpg",
                       "https://resizing.flixster.com/-XZAfHZM39UwaGJIFWKAE8fS0ak=/v3/t/assets/p15766_p_v8_ab.jpg",
                       "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/The_Incredibles_%282004_animated_feature_film%29.jpg",
                       "https://images.moviesanywhere.com/5948f139cd669fb5984d2c782e7678be/99cedd1f-ae78-4026-a3e8-b79840b71cbc.jpg")
```

The structure (dput) of the top_voted is:

```
structure(
  list(
    title = structure(
      1:10,
      levels = c(
        "Inside Out",
        "Up",
        "Finding Nemo",
        "Coco",
        "WALL·E",
        "Monsters, Inc.",
        "Toy Story",
        "The Lion King",
        "The Incredibles",
        "Shrek"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    vote_count = c(
      19463L,
      18857L,
      18061L,
      17742L,
      17446L,
      17189L,
      17152L,
      16991L,
      16584L,
      15765L
    ),
    image_url = c(
      "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_insideout_19751_af12286c.jpeg",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Up_%282009_film%29.jpg",
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmYxZjg3OWEtNzg5Yi00M2YzLWI1YzYtYTQ0NTgwNzhjN2E1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYjQ5NjM0Y2YtNjZkNC00ZDhkLWJjMWItN2QyNzFkMDE3ZjAxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODIxMzk5NjA@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_walle_19753_69f7ff00.jpeg",
      "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/p_monstersinc_19751_55afa07a.jpeg",
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDU2ZWJlMjktMTRhMy00ZTA5LWEzNDgtYmNmZTEwZTViZWJkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDQ2OTk4MzI@._V1_.jpg",
      "https://resizing.flixster.com/-XZAfHZM39UwaGJIFWKAE8fS0ak=/v3/t/assets/p15766_p_v8_ab.jpg",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/The_Incredibles_%282004_animated_feature_film%29.jpg",
      "https://images.moviesanywhere.com/5948f139cd669fb5984d2c782e7678be/99cedd1f-ae78-4026-a3e8-b79840b71cbc.jpg"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
  .internal.selfref = < pointer:0x00000199ac3d2d70 >
)
```

```
plot_top_voted <- ggplot(data = top_voted, aes(
  x = reorder(title, -vote_count),
  y = vote_count,
  fill = title
)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(fill = "Title",
       title = "Top 10 Voted Movies",
       x = "Title",
       y = "Vote Count")+
  geom_image(aes(image=image_url), size=0.1, position = position_nudge(y=10))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12, angle = 54, hjust = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust=0.5))



plot_top_voted
```

The above code works perfectly in my R studio. However geom_image does not work in Kaggle as they don't support ggimage package.

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput(top_voted)`?

Comment: @Quinten Done. Updated the question with dput.

Comment: What do you mean when saying “Kaggle” doesn’t support ggimage?  As far as I know Kaggle is a data repository and challenge presenter. You can use any language.

Comment: @IRTFM I know I can use any language but there are some limitations in Kaggle. The ggimage will not work. When we execute Rmarkdown with full code, it throws out error as "There's no package called ggimage but no errors in R studio for desktop.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem with Rmarkdown or Rstudio. There clearly is a package named `ggimage` but it not installed at whatever set of libraries is available to the working environment. Saying “it doesn’t work” with no example that fails is not going to support any solid answer. At the very least you should be able to install it and load.

Comment: In Kaggle, when I run the above code (mentioned in question as Rmarkdown), it says "cannot find function geom_image". So I tried to install the package (even though it is not needed in Kaggle. All you need to do is enable the package with library(ggimage)), as install.packages ("ggimage") and ran the script. Kaggle threw me an error as "There is no package called ggimage". But the same script works fine on my laptop. So, in short, Kaggle does not support ggimage package, and am looking for an alternative. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: Do you need to specify your repository? https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/r-tip-check-what-repos-you-are-using/. Perhaps the versions of R and the packages at the unspecified repository are out of sync.